# What is the syntax for pivot tables in Pandas? Docs don't seem to be right?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I might be totally crazy, but I'm reading [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html?highlight=pivot_table#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) for `pivot_table` in Pandas, and even [some guides](http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html)

Literally using the example from the docs with my own data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Produces an error:

> pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
>   NameError: name 'pivot_table' is not defined

What am I doing wrong? Is there an additional import I need?

Comment: It's a top level function you need `pd.pivot_table`, some of the code in the docs does the following `from pandas import *` which is why it works there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table) is a top-level function, as such you need to qualify it using `pd.pivot_table`.

The code in the docs assumes you've done the following:

`from pandas import *`

Which is where the confusion stems from.

So from the example in the docs:

```
In [41]:
t="""A   B   C      D
0  foo one small  1
1  foo one large  2
2  foo one large  2
3  foo two small  3
4  foo two small  3
5  bar one large  4
6  bar one small  5
7  bar two small  6
8  bar two large  7"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    9 non-null object
B    9 non-null object
C    9 non-null object
D    9 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 360.0+ bytes
```

The folllowing produces an error

```
In [42]:
pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-98a5be0e193b> in <module>()
----> 1 pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)

NameError: name 'pivot_table' is not defined
```

Whilst the following works:

```
In [43]:
pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)

Out[43]:
C        large  small
A   B                
bar one      4      5
    two      7      6
foo one      4      1
    two    NaN      6
```

As does this:

```
In [44]:
from pandas import *
pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)

Out[44]:
C        large  small
A   B                
bar one      4      5
    two      7      6
foo one      4      1
    two    NaN      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below lines in the beginning of the code,

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import *
```

The reason being pivot_table is a top level function and to use it we need to import all functions from pandas.

Technically we will not talk about what is a top level function now :)
I leave it to your interest to explore :)